# Is there any way to sneak attack oozes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, sneak-attack

Playing a rogue/wizard one of my important tasks is to improve my opportunities for sneak attack. While undead, constructs, plants and oozes are normally immune to being sneak attacked there are ways to bypass this immunity:

- **Undead:** Greater Truedeath Weapon Augment Crystal (MIC, p. 66), the spell Grave Strike (Cle 1st), or the Alternative rogue Class Feature "Death's Ruin" (1/2 sneak attack)
- **Constructs:** Greater Demolition Weapon Augment Crystal (MIC, p. 65), or the spell Golem Strike (Sor/Wiz 1st)
- **Plants:** the spell Vine Strike (Druid 1st)
- **Oozes:** ?

While the above list is not meant to be complete, I entirely failed to find a possibility to sneak attack oozes. So: Is anybody aware of a spell, an Alternative Class Feature or a magic item for delivering sneak attacks on oozes?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Deathstrike Bracers

Also in the Magic Item Compendium, on page 93, you will find the *deathstrike bracers*, which have the effect that:

> When activated, *deathstrike bracers* allow you to use melee weapons to deal extra damage from critical hits and sneak attacks to  constructs, elementals,  oozes, plants, and undead as if they were not immune to such extra damage.

The effect lasts for a round, and can be used 3 times a day - so it doesn't let you deal precision-based damage to anything you like all the time, but you can pop the effect when you've gotten into a good position and can make the maximum use of it. I'd consider them a must-have item for a melee rogue, and as per [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133497/28402), it seems the effect should still work with thrown melee weapons like daggers, so it's potentially of use to a ranged rogue using throwing weapons.

Answer (score 9):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no official ooze-specific version of Vinestrike/Truedeath/Demolition/etc., that will let you take full advantage of your sneak attack against oozes.

The best option I'm aware of is the **Penetrating Strike** ACF (Dungeonscape, p. 13).  This option allows a rogue to inflict 1/2 of their normal sneak attack bonus damage against a flanked target who would normally be immune.  This will work against oozes, though of course it's much weaker than the type-specific options listed in the question (half damage, only works on flanked targets).

Comment: I did not realize Penetrating Strike works on all types of monsters. contrary to your statement above Pentetrating Strike not weaker than *Death's Ruin*, because that also only confers *half* sneak attack damage - but it is not limited to flanking.

Comment: While it is about an year old, I am willing to note that ooze (as well as elemental) type is immune to flanking.